# problem is maven install - cannot find symbol Client

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, jboss, wildfly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4N7CJ.jpg)[image]

I have trying to maven install 
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class Client
  location: class com.beeya.googleGOC.jobProviders.impl.CareerJet
I have already include related jar file in classpath 
and i have also try with manually set jar into wildfly in modules folder 
but that issue is not solve

Comment: Can you share you pom.xml file. You need to have dependency defined in it.

Comment: yes sure i will share it

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.1</version>
</dependency>

Comment: that ablove dependency is already is added in pom.xml file

Comment: In your code you are using some third party web service API com.carrerjet.webservice.api which is not a part of dependencies included in pom.xml i.e org.apache.httpcomponents

Comment: I suggest putting in more effort to drafting your question. Not clear.

Comment: yes i am using third pary API webservices then how to solve that problem

Comment: that API of maven dependency is not available thats why i have putted related jars into classpath

Comment: @RajeshBhushan check the answer section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using third party API which is not available in any repository, you need to add local jar in dependency as,

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.carrerjet.webservice</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/yourJar.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Or you can add the your local jar to local maven repository as,

```
mvn install:install-file \
   -Dfile=<path-to-file> \
   -DgroupId=<group-id> \
   -DartifactId=<artifact-id> \
   -Dversion=<version> \
   -Dpackaging=<packaging> \
   -DgeneratePom=true
```

Where,
< path-to-file >: the phisical path to the file to load e.g -> c:\webservice-1.0.jar

< group-id >: the group that the file should be registered under e.g -> com.carrerjet.webservice

< artifact-id >: the artifact name for the file e.g -> api

< version >: the version of the file e.g -> 1.0

< packaging >: the packaging of the file e.g. -> jar

In this case, you need to provide dependency in pom as below,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.carrerjet.webservice</groupId>
        <artifactId>api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: when i put inside the pom.xml then this type of error shown -Missing artifact com.careerjet.webservices

Comment: How to know what i can write in artifactId ?

Comment: but one more issue is created when i will hit Api then - org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/HttpClient

Comment: cllick on above link - enter image description here which is available above the image file. in the image file error is shown when i will hit Api

Comment: @RajeshBhushan your original question is solved. Please accept the answer, it encourages to answer more questions.You can raise another question for  nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.